# How to store multiple arrays in single object in local storage and retrieve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks, local-storage

I have 5 arrays namely and in order to decrease the amount of code I am trying to add all arrays in a single object and push that object into local storage. Later retrieve the object and use the properties. But when the user iam console logging the object, it is showing property values as undefined. I want that when the user first time enters the site and there is no data in the local storage object, then an object with empty array values should be pushed to local storage, something like this:-

```
{videoData: [],playlistName: [],playlistObj: [],videoIds: [],notesArr: []}
```

But instead object with undefined values is being pushed:-

```
{videoData: undefined,playlistName: undefined,playlistObj: undefined,videoIds: undefined,notesArr: undefined}
```

Function to retrieve data =

```
const getStoredDataFunc = () => {
  let videoData = localStorage.getItem(`storageData`)
  if (videoData) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`storageData`))
  }
  else {
    return {
      videoData: [],
      playlistName: [],
      playlistObj: [],
      videoIds: [],
      notesArr: []
    }
  }
}

console.log(getStoredDataFunc)  // {}
```

States:-

```
const [videoData, setvideoData] = useState(getStoredDataFunc().videoData);
const [playlistName, setplaylistName] = useState(getStoredDataFunc().playlistName)
const [playlistObj, setplaylistObj] = useState(getStoredDataFunc().playlistObj)
const [videoIds, setvideoIds] = useState(getStoredDataFunc().videoIds)
const [notesArr, setnotesArr] = useState(getStoredDataFunc().notesArr)
```

Add to local storage -

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let obj = {
      videoData: videoData,
      playlistName: playlistName,
      playlistObj: playlistObj,
      videoIds: videoIds,
      notesArr: notesArr
    }
    
    localStorage.setItem("storageData", JSON.stringify(obj))
  }, [videoData, playlistObj, playlistName, videoIds, notesArr])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you're setting the data in these arrays in state, it's overwriting [] to undefined.
Can you share the code logic about how you're using these setter functions -`setvideoData`, `setplaylistName`  etc.